# Unable to run mockttp with Cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress, http-mock, mockttp

I'm trying to run the [mockttp](https://github.com/httptoolkit/mockttp) with cypress. I used the example that's listed in [project github](https://github.com/httptoolkit/mockttp#get-testing). I changed the port to run on 3000 but I am getting an error saying *Cannot add rules before the server is started*.

```
/*global cy:true,before:true*/
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/cypress/types/index.d.ts" />

const superagent = require("superagent");
const mockServer = require("mockttp").getLocal();

describe('mockttp test' , () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockServer.start(3000);
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        mockServer.stop();
    });
  it("lets you mock requests, and assert on the results", async () => {
    // Mock your endpoints
    const mockedPath = mockServer.forGet("/mocked-path");
    
    // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    await mockedPath.thenReply(200, "A mocked response");

    // Make a request
    const response = await superagent.get("http://localhost:3000/mocked-path");

    // Assert on the results
    expect(response.text).to.equal("A mocked response");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the server is actually started before running your test, by waiting for the promises returned by `mockServer.start()` (and by `.stop()`).

You can either make your beforeEach & afterEach functions `async` and then `await` those lines, or you can just add `return` to return the promise so that Mocha waits for them automatically.